# List colors in ComboBox without transparent color

Tags: wpf

I wan't in my application ComboBox with list of colors, but I don't won't this list to contain Transparent color. Additionaly colors in list must be from Colors class. 
I search in net and find something like that:

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetType" 
ObjectType="{x:Type System:Type}" x:Key="colorsTypeOdp">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <System:String>System.Windows.Media.Colors, PresentationCore,
        Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</System:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource colorsTypeOdp}"  
MethodName="GetProperties" x:Key="colorPropertiesOdp">
    </ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox Width="80" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource colorPropertiesOdp}}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="18" Margin="0,0,0,2">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" 
              BorderBrush="Black" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Background="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                    </ComboBox>
```

Anyone know how to do this taks? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is not direct way in xaml. You have to collect the properties of Colors in source code and remove the transparent one manually. You can put the resulting collection in a property that can be bound from xaml in a cleaner way than now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create your own list of `Color` instances from the [Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx) class and exclude the `Colors.Transparent` color from this list. Then you can bind this list to your combo box's `ItemsSource` property.

To get the list of `Color` instances from the `Colors` class, you can use the following code snippet:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
   Color color = property.GetValue(null, null) as Color;
```